# PHP waits until a loop completes

Tags: php, sockets, udp

I am trying to print a UDP message in a while loop which runs 10 times in PHP. the problem is that it waits until the loop completes and then the message is printed 10 times but I want to print it on each iteration of the loop not at the completion of the loop. Here is my code.

```
<?php
  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,SOL_UDP);
  socket_bind($socket,$ip_address,$port);

  $i = 0;
  while($i < 10)
  {
    $i++;
    $FROM = '';
    $PORT = 0;

    socket_recvfrom($socket,$buffer,1024,0,$from,$PORT);
    echo "Receiving $buffer from IP $FROM and Port $PORT", PHP_EOL);
    flush();
    sleep(1);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Is it a command line script or do you call it from a browser?

Comment: I call it from a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call **[ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)** to flush the output buffer, after your call to **flush()**.

> This function will send the contents of the output buffer (if any)

If accessing from a browser,  `header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );` might need to be added at the top of your webpage

Also an **ob_start()** at the beginning of the script turns on output buffering.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the post on php.net regarding browsers and ob_flush http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109699

Comment: As you are calling it from a browser, Add the following to your PHP script `header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );`

Comment: Also, try an *ob_start()* at the beginning of your script. One of these should work. :)